# Authentication strategies for dealing with users that willingly provide their credentials to others

Tags: authentication

Let's say we have an employee that has an account on an online system that she does her work on. Let's say she doesn't want to do the work.  So she provides her login credentials to someone else.  2FA authentication in this case is useless because she will willingly provide the 2FA code to the other person.

I can think of a couple of things that could help somewhat:

1. IP restrict her account.  A PITA for us though due to dynamic IPs.
2. Prevent more than one login at the same time.  Still not too useful as the other person could still work during off-hours.  Or the primary worker could simply not work at all.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I think you need to describe what resources you have and what constraints you have. There are a couple dozen things that come to my mind but none of them might be applicable to you. Can you also refine the question? As it stands, it looks like you are asking for a wide list of options.

Comment: This is a policy issue that must be solved with policy. Don't fix policy with tech, it don't work.

Answer (score 5):

3. Update the appropriate policy (password policy, generally) such that sharing credentials with a third party is a firing offense.

You'll need to get HR on board with that, which can be tough; they like to be the ones who decide what's a firing offense.

Once that rule is in place, then you merely need to detect this use case once or twice, and set an example.  Layer 8 problem, layer 8 solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your wording is wrong!

2FA can help.

Since 2FA is more than OTP values issued by a Google Authenticator app!

So lets drill this down, so you can think of how high you want to raise the fence!

## Using crappy Google Authenticator thingy

You are right. If you are using the Google Authenticator you end up with even two problems.
Users can share the created OTP value, but they can even [share the initial QR Code, if you are using TOTP](https://netknights.it/en/the-problem-with-the-google-authenticator/).

So drop this.

## Avoid sharing inital QR code

To avoid the sharing of initial QR codes, you could use a 2step enrollment, that binds the token to the user's smartphone or you could use hardware keyfob  OTP tokens.

But again you are right, the user could share (or even stream!) the generated OTP value.

## Avoid sharing OTP values, use Push

If you want to avoid, that users share OTP values, then get rid of OTP values.
And in fact 2FA does not only mean OTP, it can be much more.

You could use PUSH tokens. The user gets a notification on her smartphone and cryptographically signs a challenge, to verify, that she wants to log in.

However, you are right, the "attacker" could still tell his fried, "hey friend, I am trying to log in, please confirm on your smartphone!".

## Avoid simple confirmation, require presence

The problem with push is, that the 2nd factor, the device does not need to be present with the user, who is currently logging in.

So we need to ensure, that the device is present.

You could do this with classical smartcards or with u2f or webauthn devices.
This way, the user/human who is currently logging in, needs to have this device with him to be able to log in.
This device can not be cloned and the cryptographical material on this device is unique.
So the "attacker" could ask his friend that he wants to log in. But as long as the fried (and his device) is not present, the "attacker" can not log in.

So this would be technically the best way to avoid your mentioned attack vector.

Comment: Or fire those sharing credentials. One case is enough.

Comment: As @gowenfawr said means to identify misuse makes sense on top.